# rsync --delete deleted most files in the destination directory, why?

Tags: rsync

I got my config files in `/etc` folder all messed up because I did not take care of shell expansion while doing rsync:

```
rsync --progress --delete -avhHe ssh /etc/logrotate.d/{httpd,mariadb,php-fpm,ppp,wpa_supplicant,yum} root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

I think the problem is that the '.' following logrotate got expanded and subsequently some folders such as `/etc/httpd` got deleted.

I want to learn from this mistake by doing it correctly. How do I prevent shell expansion when rsync multiple files with ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command boils down to this:

```
rsync --delete --recursive /etc/logrotate.d/{httpd,mariadb,php-fpm,ppp,wpa_supplicant,yum} root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

The `.` in there has its literal meaning - it's part of the name - so that isn't the problem. The part in `{}` is subject to [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion): each comma-separated part gets expanded and concatenated to the part of that argument that came before (`/etc/logrotate.d/`). (It'd also get anything after, if there were anything: `a{BC}d` expands to `aBd aCd`).

So this command is equivalent to

```
rsync --delete --recursive /etc/logrotate.d/httpd /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb /etc/logrotate.d/php-fpm /etc/logrotate.d/ppp /etc/logrotate.d/wpa_supplicant /etc/logrotate.d/yum root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

or to pick just one directory out so it's short:

```
rsync --delete --recursive /etc/logrotate.d/httpd root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

rsync interprets the "from" location as a single entity, and if it **doesn't** end with a `/` it makes a new file or directory with just the last part of that name inside the given destination path: here, that's `httpd`. So this makes a `/etc/httpd` on the destination and copies the contents of `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` into it.

With `--delete`, it will then [delete everything](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) that **wasn't** in `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` on the source. The problem— since `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` probably doesn't exist at all, copying it and deleting any files that weren't present on the source means **deleting everything in all of those directories**. If it did exist, its contents won't be the same as `/etc/httpd`, so (almost) everything will be deleted.

So the problem is just that you have the `logrotate.d` part there at all, when you really meant to copy the same directories under `/etc`. What you probably meant was just:

```
rsync --progress --delete -avhHe ssh /etc/{httpd,mariadb,php-fpm,ppp,wpa_supplicant,yum} root@my.ipaddress:/etc
```

That copies `/etc/httpd` and its contents to `/etc/httpd` on the destination, and so on. If you meant to copy things inside `logrotate.d`, put that in the path on both sides.

One thing you may find useful is the [`-n` or `--dry-run` option](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) to `rsync`:

> -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made

That will show you a preview of what would happen, but not actually make any changes on either end. You can use that to check it's what you want before running the real thing.

---

You asked how to prevent shell expansion in the arguments you gave to `rsync`. As above, I don't think that's actually what you want given the problem you had, but if you do ever need to: brace expansions don't take place inside quotes, so `"a{BC}d"` stays as `a{BC}d` literally.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer, I think my mistake is that I assume the origin path will be used at the destination and tried combining files and folders from different directory levels. When it didn't work out, I tried using a single level, but forgot to change the destination to `/etc/logrotate.d`. In my panic, I mistakenly thought this to be a shell expansion issue. Thanks for pointing out the dry-run which I should rightly do first. :)